# 'Int' is not convertible to 'Range<Int>

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of `PFObjects` and I've created a new array: `restaurantNames` to store all their names. Now I'm trying to print the names on UIPageView, but I get the error:

```
'Int' is not convertible to 'Range<Int>'
```

Code:

```
private func getItemController(itemIndex: Int) -> PageItemController? {

    let restaurantNames = finalRestaurantArray.map { $0.objectForKey("Name") }

    if itemIndex < finalRestaurantArray.count {
        let pageItemController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ItemController") as PageItemController
        pageItemController.itemIndex = itemIndex
        pageItemController.restaurantName = restaurantNames[itemIndex]
        //pageItemController.imageName = finalRestaurantArray[itemIndex]
        return pageItemController
    }

    return nil
}
```

The actual PFObject array looks like this (`restaurantNames` contains the array of just names):

```
[<Restaurant: 0x7feb9252cfc0, objectId: LA74J92QDA, localId: (null)> {
    Name = "Restaurant 1";        
    City = "New York";
    Closed = 1;
    Country = "United States";
    FoodType = Japanese;
}, <Restaurant: 0x7feb926afa00, objectId: 0aKFrpKN46, localId: (null)> {
    Name = "Restaurant 2";        
    City = "San Francisco";
    Closed = 1;
    Country = "United States";
    FoodType = Italian;
}]
```

Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/U63TFMRV

Comment: Where is `println`, add that code to the question. Add the println of restaurantNames to the question.

Comment: Probably not relevant to your problem in this case, but why not just use `finalRestaurantArray[itemIndex]["Name"]`  It's significantly more efficient than rebuilding the name array each time you want a page.

Comment: And on what line does the error occur?

Comment: Thanks @David, I'll actually give that a try.

Comment: @Rachel: Can you clarify on what line exactly the compiler error occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is confusing to the compiler:

```
let restaurantNames = finalRestaurantArray.map { $0.objectForKey("Name") }
```

This creates an `[AnyObject?]` which is a notoriously difficult for the compiler to deal with, and the errors you get are often confusing (because of various promotions and overloads).

Step 1 is that you should avoid `AnyObject` whenever possible. So `finalRestaurantArray` should be an array of the actual objects rather than `[AnyObject]`, or even dictionaries. Then your map would return a `[String]` like I believe you want it to.

You *can* hack this into place like this:

```
// Avoid this
let restaurantNames = finalRestaurantArray.map { $0.objectForKey("Name") as String }
```

And if anything goes wrong, it'll crash. Don't do that. Get your data out of `AnyObject` as fast as you can (and get it out of `Dictionary` as fast as you can, too), and turn it into real model objects that can guarantee they'll return a value.

Comment: thanks for the advice. This was really helpful. I just wanted to be clear. Was the code you suggested a good solution to this problem? (because your comment says avoid this): `let restaurantNames = finalRestaurantArray.map { $0.objectForKey("Name") as String }`

Comment: Don't do the "as String" bit; that's a hack that will crash on you someday. Create a Restaurant struct to hold your data. Initialize it with whatever your input data is (whatever is today in your `AnyObject`).

Comment: So I need to convert the `[AnyObject]` into `[PFObject]` then use the map to return the `[String]`? I've been searching to figure out how to downcast `[AnyObject]` into `[PFObject]`, but haven't found a correct solution.

Comment: Don't downcast it to `PFObject`. Create a strongly typed object. See `PFSubclassing` https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Protocols/PFSubclassing.html. Your object should have a property `name` that returns a `String`. If you're using `objectForKey:` widely through your code, you're always going to have headaches with `AnyObject?` returns.