# Downcast [AnyObject] to [String] and [PFObject]

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of `[AnyObject]` and would like to cast it as `[PFObject]` and `[String]`. What is the proper way to do this? I was told `as String` wasn't the ideal way to downcast from `AnyObject`.

Currently using this code to cast the object within the array as String:

```
    restaurantNames = finalRestaurantArray.map { $0.objectForKey("Name") as String }
```

The array looks like this:

```
[<Restaurant: 0x7feb9252cfc0, objectId: LA74J92QDA, localId: (null)> {
    Name = "Restaurant 1";        
    City = "New York";
    Closed = 1;
    Country = "United States";
    FoodType = Japanese;
}, <Restaurant: 0x7feb926afa00, objectId: 0aKFrpKN46, localId: (null)> {
    Name = "Restaurant 2";        
    City = "San Francisco";
    Closed = 1;
    Country = "United States";
    FoodType = Italian;
}]
```

Comment: What you're doing is right so I don't see what the question is. Is it not working somehow? If that's the case, please explain what's going wrong.

Comment: Is the problem that you don't like using AnyObject? Then cast the whole array first to `[PFObject]` (as you've already suggested).

Comment: @matt I was asking because my other question received an answer that suggested downcasting with `as String` was a bad idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099082

Comment: Yes, but that has something to do with PFObject. You were advised _not_ to have an array of `[AnyObject]` and _not_ to use `objectForKey`. But you didn't take that advice. And in any case that isn't what you asked _here_. You asked a purely linguistic question about casting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
let restaurantNames = finalRestaurantArray.map {
  $0["Name"] as? String ?? ""
}
```

The `??` puts default value, if downcasting fails.

Comment: I was asking because my other question received an answer that suggested downcasting with `as String` was a bad idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099082

Comment: @Emma you can explicitly declare a type for *restaurantNames*. In this case compiler will know how to try to cast it.